# NtOsKrnl.exe uses 100% of my disk

Tags: ntoskrnl.exe

I read a previous question and the answer.  I have the same problem.  At random times, and often when coming out of a sleep, my Win 8.1 Pro system is effectively "frozen" as NtOsKrnl.exe is using 100% of the disk.  When it stops doing so, everything runs again.  This is very frustrating as it can take anywhere from less than a minute to several minutes.

The prior answer said to download Sys Internals which I did.  It said to "run Process Monitor" AS ADMIN.  I don't know what "AS ADMIN" means.  But I did start Process monitor up.  Next I was supposed to double click on system, but there is no "system" on my Process Monitor.  Finally I was supposed to see a "Threads" tab, but it is not there.

This is the actual previous reply:

Process Monitor from the SysInternals Suite should let you find out more information about what is acting up. To use it start it up as Admin and double click System to bring up it's properties. From there select the "Threads" tab and it will show you the stack as well as which module is staying busy.

I can't seem to get a Print Screen of what I see in this  post.

Carl